# How to create default constraint on the table of Firebird to assign auto-generated UUID value

Tags: sql, firebird, uuid, default-constraint

I am trying to define a table with a column type of UUID (`CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS`). After reading through the Firebird 3.0 Developer's Guide, I found only context-variables/simple expression/constant are supported. I would like to know if there is a way to define a default constraint on a table to call `GEN_UUID()` to assign UUID for insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with a `DEFAULT` clause, as that only allows literals and a select number of what the Firebird documentation refers to as ['context variables'](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-contextvars).

To do what you want, you need to create a before insert [trigger](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-ddl-trigger.html) to generate the value. Something like this:

```sql
create trigger bi_yourtable before insert on yourtable
as
begin
  new.uuid_column = gen_uuid();
end
```

Or, if you don't want unconditional generation of the UUID:

```sql
create trigger bi_yourtable before insert on yourtable
as
begin
  if (new.uuid_column is null) then
  begin
    new.uuid_column = gen_uuid();
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!  Yes, I got the same idea from Firebird's developer guide. This is quite different from other databases as the sensitive default.

Comment: @Andrew It is the behaviour for `DEFAULT` specified by the SQL standard, the fact some database support other types of expressions is a non-standard extension.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for correcting my misconception. So glad that I can learn from the expert of firebird (Thumb up emoji)